# Azure Functions - TimerTrigger - get next scheduled occurrence

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Is there a way to get the next scheduled occurrence of an Azure Timer function? This issue seems to say that `TimerInfo` should have a schedule property, but I'm not seeing it in .NET 8.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/954#issuecomment-1238433441

```
public static void CronJob([TimerTrigger("*/15 * * * * *")] TimerInfo timerInfo)
{
    var schedule = timerInfo.Schedule as CronSchedule;
    var next = schedule.GetNextOccurrence(DateTime.UtcNow);

    . . .
}
```

Is the `GetNextOccurrence` ability just gone now? Is there any workaround?

(Cross Posted: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/discussions/2204)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `Isolated Process` does not have  `GetNextOccurrence` as it uses different module.

- `In-process` uses:
  `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` which provides method`GetNextOccurrence`.
- `Isolated process` uses:
  `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.sdk` and
  `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer` which does not provide method `GetNextOccurrence`.

As per MSFT mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1459140/ttimerinfo-schedulestatus-next-is-not-showing-next) and As per the GitHub [comment](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/954#issuecomment-1238433441)

> Next in`ScheduleStatus.Next` isn’t the next schedule time from the current invocation – it’s the value that was used to determine when to invoke the current invocation. The naming of the properties of `ScheduleStatus` are from the perspective of the scheduler, not from the perspective of the current invocation. This is by design, though I can appreciate why there may be some confusion.
>
> ```
> TimerInfo timerInfo) {
>     var schedule = timerInfo.Schedule as CronSchedule;
>     var next = schedule.GetNextOccurrence(DateTime.UtcNow);
>
>     . . . }
> ```

`timerInfo.Schedule` is only available in `In-process` model. Currently .NET 8 is `Isolated process`.

I used `NCronTab` to get next Occurrence.

> **Note**: `NCronTab` support only 5 `*` expression method. {second} expression is not supported in `NCrontab`.

For reference check these documents: [NCrontab: Crontab for .NET (github.com)](https://github.com/atifaziz/NCrontab) and Microsoft document

**`TimeTrigger1.cs`:**

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Company.Function
{
    public class TimerTrigger1
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public TimerTrigger1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<TimerTrigger1>();
        }

        [Function("TimerTrigger1")]
        public void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */2 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

            var time = CrontabSchedule.Parse("*/2 * * * *");

            var next = time.GetNextOccurrence(DateTime.Now);

            _logger.LogInformation($"next occurence is : {next}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**`OUTPUT`:**

`[image]

Comment: Thanks - that was my understanding too - was hoping that I was missing something.